# Can I combine {% include %} with custom filter in django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, templates

First I have created custom filter that makes autoindentation:

**templatetags/indent.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='indent')
@stringfilter
def indent(value, arg):
    import re
    regex = re.compile('^', re.M)
    return re.sub(regex, ' ' * int(arg), value)
```

and I want to include subtemplate that will be indented by certain number of spaces (eg. 8):

Is this allowed in django's templates:

```
{% load indent %}

{% include "footer.html"|indent:"8" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you do can do it by using [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#filter):

```
{% load indent %}

{% filter indent:"8" %}
    {% include "footer.html" %}
{% endfilter %}
```